# Check whether a type is an instance of Show in Haskell at runtime?

Tags: haskell

Suppose I have a simple data type in Haskell for storing a value:

```
data V a = V a
```

I want to make V an instance of Show, regardless of a's type. If a is an instance of Show, then `show (V a)` should return `show a` otherwise an error message should be returned. Or in Pseudo-Haskell:

```
instance Show (V a) where
    show (V a) = if a instanceof Show
                   then show a
                   else "Some Error."
```

How could this behaviour be implemented in Haskell?

Comment: Haskell is a fully type-erased language; at runtime, the memory-allocated structures don't contain tags that can be used to recover their types or the classes that these types implement.  Therefore, there is no `instanceof` operator like Java or similar languages provide. (There are  more advanced techniques that can be used in some cases to similar runtime type reflection, but if you're a beginner you should stick to the basics first!)

Comment: This behaviour can't be implemented, because philosophically, _every type is in every class_. Granted, if the compiler can't _find_ a `Show` instance for some type you try to `show`, there will be an error; but this is understood to be conceptually “you forgot to write the necessary instance” instead of “you tryed to show a type which _is not_ showable“. Type classes are open, anybody can later define instances for some library class. The compiler can't possibly prove that this won't happen, when it compiles the library!

Comment: That said: the behaviour can be emulated with [overlapping instances](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.1/docs/html/users_guide/type-class-extensions.html#instance-overlap), which are considered a bit of an ugly (or even unsafe) hack. Perhaps better matching the idea are [closed type families](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/ext-f/axioms-extended.pdf), though they don't readily allow you to implement that show instance.

Comment: You implement this behaviour by writing `instance Show a => Show (V a) where ...`. Then the "Some Error" becomes a compile time type error.

Comment: some links relevant to @leftaroundabout's comment http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/typeEQ.html  https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/AdvancedOverlap

Comment: Nope, even with overlapping instances you can't match on a typeclass context. Exercise: try to do your worst hack to "tell if something is an instance of Show". I'm pretty willing to bet that even incoherent instances won't allow such a thing...

Comment: @sclv I have a solution that appears to give the correct answer in all my tests: `type family IsInstanceOfShow a :: Bool; type instance IsInstanceOfShow a = True; instance Show a`...

Comment: @DanielWagner hah! points for obeying the letter and not the spirit :-P

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As I said in a comment, the runtime objects allocated in memory don't have type tags in a Haskell program.  There is therefore no universal `instanceof` operation like in, say, Java.

It's also important to consider the implications of the following.  In Haskell, to a first approximation (i.e., ignoring some fancy stuff that beginners shouldn't tackle too soon), all runtime function calls are **monomorphic**.  I.e., the compiler knows, directly or indirectly, the monomorphic (non-generic) type of every function call in an executable program.  Even though your `V` type's `show` function has a generic type:

```
-- Specialized to `V a`
show :: V a -> String  -- generic; has variable `a`
```

...you can't actually write a program that calls the function at runtime without, directly or indirectly, telling the compiler exactly what type `a` will be in every single call.  So for example:

```
-- Here you tell it directly that `a := Int`
example1 = show (V (1 :: Int)) 

-- Here you're not saying which type `a` is, but this just "puts off" 
-- the decision—for `example2` to be called, *something* in the call
-- graph will have to pick a monomorphic type for `a`.
example2 :: a -> String
example2 x = show (V x) ++ example1
```

Seen in this light, hopefully you can spot the problem with what you're asking:

```
instance Show (V a) where
    show (V a) = if a instanceof Show
                   then show a
                   else "Some Error."
```

Basically, since the type for the `a` parameter will be known at compilation time for any actual call to your `show` function, there's no point to testing for this type at runtime—you can test for it at compilation time!  Once you grasp this, you're led to Will Sewell's suggestion:

```
-- No call to `show (V x)` will compile unless `x` is of a `Show` type.
instance Show a => Show (V a) where ...
```

---

**EDIT:** A more constructive answer perhaps might be this: your `V` type needs to be a tagged union of multiple cases.  This does require using the `GADTs` extension:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

-- This definition requires `GADTs`.  It has two constructors:
data V a where
  -- The `Showable` constructor can only be used with `Show` types.
  Showable   :: Show a => a -> V a
  -- The `Unshowable` constructor can be used with any type.
  Unshowable :: a -> V a

instance Show (V a) where
  show (Showable a) = show a
  show (Unshowable a) = "Some Error."
```

But this isn't a runtime check of whether a type is a `Show` instance—your code is responsible for knowing at compilation time where the `Showable` constructor is to be used.

Comment: What if, for some reason, you *really did* want to return an error message for non-Show types?

Comment: @immibis: Now that I think of it, you could use the last version with the `Show a` constraint, and [the compiler option to defer type errors to runtime](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/defer-type-errors.html).  But the compiler will still warn you that your program may fail at runtime—it will even tell you exactly which lines would fail!

Comment: *return* an error message, not crash the program with one.

Comment: Why do you dismiss polymorphic recursion as not being for beginners?

Comment: @dfeuer: I was thinking of `RankNTypes`, actually.

Comment: `RankNTypes` is not for beginners (and not yet in standard Haskell), but polymorphic recursion hits as soon as you need to work with non-regular types, and those appear in structures like Okasaki's implicit queues.

Answer (score 13):

You can with this library: https://github.com/mikeizbicki/ifcxt. Being able to call `show` on a value that may or may not have a `Show` instance is one of the first examples it gives. This is how you could adapt that for `V a`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

import IfCxt
import Data.Typeable

mkIfCxtInstances ''Show

data V a = V a

instance forall a. IfCxt (Show a) => Show (V a) where
    show (V a) = ifCxt (Proxy::Proxy (Show a))
        (show a)
        "<<unshowable>>"
```

---

This is the essence of this library:

```
class IfCxt cxt where
    ifCxt :: proxy cxt -> (cxt => a) -> a -> a

instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} IfCxt cxt where ifCxt _ t f = f
```

I don't fully understand it, but this is how I think it works:

It doesn't violate the "open world" assumption any more than

```
instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} Show a where
    show _ = "<<unshowable>>"
```

does. The approach is actually pretty similar to that: adding a default case to fall back on for all types that do not have an instance in scope. However, it adds some indirection to not make a mess of the existing instances (and to allow different functions to specify different defaults). `IfCxt` works as a a "meta-class", a class on constraints, that indicates whether those instances exist, with a default case that indicates "false.":

```
instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} IfCxt cxt where ifCxt _ t f = f
```

It uses TemplateHaskell to generate a long list of instances for that class:

```
instance {-# OVERLAPS #-} IfCxt (Show Int) where ifCxt _ t f = t
instance {-# OVERLAPS #-} IfCxt (Show Char) where ifCxt _ t f = t
```

which also implies that any instances that were not in scope when `mkIfCxtInstances` was called will be considered non-existing.

The `proxy cxt` argument is used to pass a `Constraint` to the function, the `(cxt => a)` argument (I had no idea RankNTypes allowed that) is an argument that can *use* the constraint `cxt`, but as long as that argument is unused, the constraint doesn't need to be solved. This is similar to:

```
f :: (Show (a -> a) => a) -> a -> a
f _ x = x
```

The `proxy` argument supplies the constraint, then the `IfCxt` constraint is solved to either the `t` or `f` argument, if it's `t` then there is some `IfCxt` instance where this constraint is supplied which means it can be solved directly, if it's `f` then the constraint is never demanded so it gets dropped.

---

This solution is imperfect (as new modules can define new `Show` instances which won't work unless it also calls `mkIfCxtInstances`), but being able to do that *would* violate the open world assumption.

Comment: There is a more recent `if-instances` package that uses compiler plugins instead of th

Answer (score 2):

Even if you could do this, it would be a bad design. I would recommend adding a `Show` constraint to `a`:

```
instance Show a => Show (V a) where ...
```

If you want to store members in a container data type that are not an instance of `Show`, then you should create a new data type fore them.