# Haskell: safe 'show'

Tags: haskell, typeclass

As part of a larger project written in Haskell, I am working on a small utility library to encapsulate common paradigms I use throughout my code. One function (or two functions, rather) that I was working on are `fromLeft :: Either a b -> a` and `fromRight :: Either a b -> b`, which are partial functions that are undefined (`error` to be exact) on antichiral constructors:

```
fromLeft :: Either a b -> a
fromLeft x = case x of
               (Left x) -> x
               (Right y) -> error "fromLeft: (Right _)"

fromRight :: Either a b -> b
fromRight x = case x of
                (Right x) -> x
                (Left y) -> error "fromRight: (Left _)"
```

In any case, I wanted to extend these functions if possible so that, if the `y` in the second pattern match for each function were of a type that were `show`able, it would be printed instead of `"_"`. However, there is no obvious way to go about that without putting a constraint in the signature, which would make these functions lose their generality.

Is there any extension or module voodoo that can selectively perform typeclass functions for instances of those typeclasses and return a general result for other types? More specifically, is there any way in Haskell to write a program that simulates the invalid function
`\x -> if (showable x) then show x else "_"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check whether a type is an instance of Show in Haskell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35785176/check-whether-a-type-is-an-instance-of-show-in-haskell)

Comment: https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/AdvancedOverlap has that exact problem and solutions. I would not recommend implementing them!

Comment: @ibotty That looks interesting. Thanks for the share. I may not heed your warning though :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```
fromRightWith :: (a -> String) -> Either a b -> b
fromRightWith show (Left a) = error $ "fromRight: (Left " ++ show a ++ ")"
fromRightWith _ (Right b) = b

fromRight :: Either a b -> b
fromRight = fromRightWith $ const "_"

fromRight' :: Show a => Either a b -> b
fromRight' = fromRightWith show
```

Then if, in your code, you know that `a` is an instance of `Show`, use `fromRight'`. If not, use `fromRight`:

```
instance Show MyError where
  show = -- ..

trySomething :: IO (Either MyError Value)
trySomething = --- ..

main = do
  value <- fromRight' <$> trySomething
  -- ..
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. This is more or less what I was thinking of, but @ibotty provided an interesting resource that I ultimately ended up using (at least for the time being(, for better or for worse.