# Trace debugging a polymorphic type without a Show constraint

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to debug a polymorphic function, and would love to be able to print out some intermediate values. `Debug.Trace` will allow me to print strings to the screen (unsafely) for debugging purposes.

For example

```
buggyFunction :: (SomeConstraint a, SomeMonadStack m) => a -> m Int
buggyFunction x = do 
   ...
   trace "I'm here!" $ return ()
   ...
```

If I want to trace an arbitrary value, `traceShow` works but requires the value you're calling it on to have a `Show` instance. In my case, I know that my `a` that is being used to test does have a `Show` instance I could use, but I can't just add it to my constraints because other functions then wouldn't resolve.

If I just had one type I'm calling it on, I could use `unsafeCoerce` along with a call to `show`. For example, let's say `buggyFunction` works on `Int` and while testing in GHCi I call it with `buggyFunction 5`:

```
buggyFunction :: (SomeConstraint a, SomeMonadStack m) => a -> m Int
buggyFunction x = do 
   ...
   trace ("I'm here with value " ++ show (unsafeCoerce x :: Int)) $ return ()
   ...
```

Since `unsafeCoerce` requires a concrete type, I couldn't use it as `unsafeCoerce :: a -> (Show b => b)`

How could I do this if I don't know the particular type of `a`, but I do know that it will have an instance for `Show`?

Comment: Instances aren't somehow "baked" into the values, they get passed as extra parameters to functions. In fact, values themselves don't carry any runtime type information at all. So if your function doesn't have a `Show` constraint (which would make the compiler pass the instance to the function), there is absolutely nowhere to get it from.

Comment: This is not really doable. There are half-baked ideas like https://stackoverflow.com/a/35790024/3072788 that might get you a bit further but honestly, you are better off adding the `Show` instances everywhere.

Comment: @Alec thanks for that link, somehow I missed that question when I was searching. I was really hoping there was some unsafe way to do this for debugging, since I don't think I actually can add `Show` everywhere in my case (at least not trivially).

Comment: @FyodorSoikin I understand there's no run-time information, I was hoping there might be some compile-time hack I could use to do this to force the constraint. Thanks for the input though!

Comment: Note that using `unsafeCoerce` is very dangerous: if used with the wrong type (i.e., if the runtime type is not the target type of the coercion), the behavior of the program becomes completely undefined. The resulting effect is similar to generating a random pointer to memory and then jumping to that address -- anything could happen. In the best scenario, some gibberish is printed and then a segmentation fault happens.

Comment: `#ifdef DEBUG; type SomeConstraint a = (RealSomeConstraint a, Show a); #else; type SomeConstraint a = RealSomeConstraint #endif`

Comment: @chi Definitely important to remember. Like I mentioned before, this is strictly for debugging with known parameters, not used in the more open environment.