# Can I filter a type level list based on availability of a certain class?

Tags: haskell, types, constraints, type-families

I can separate functions from nullary values with a type family like this:

```
type family Funs (ts :: [*]) :: [*]
  where
    Funs '[ ] = '[ ]
    Funs ((a -> b): ts) = (a -> b): Funs ts
    Funs (k: ts) = Funs ts
```

What I would like is to separate types that satisfy a constraint, for instance `Show`. An attempt by analogy:

```
type family Showable (ts :: [*]) :: [*]
  where
    Showable '[ ] = '[ ]
    Showable ((Show a => a): ts) = a: Showable ts
    Showable (k: ts) = Showable ts
```

— Leads to an error:

```
    • Illegal qualified type: Show a => a
    • In the equations for closed type family ‘Showable’
      In the type family declaration for ‘Showable’
   |
35 |     Showable ((Show a => a): ts) = a: Showable ts
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

What can be done? I am fine with a solution that uses Template Haskell, or lowly hackery of any sort.

Comment: Consider checking out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35790024/2288659). It's not a full answer to your question (it answers how to hack together this type information at runtime via TH, whereas you want it as a compile-time type), but it may point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe that it is possible to do this easily (without TH) because of the open-world assumption: GHC basically will never resolve the negative of a class constraint, because there might be more instances somewhere that make it true (and don't play nicely with the separate compilation strategy that GHC/Haskell uses). So, it is not generally possible to---from pure "regular" Haskell code---decide whether or not a type has a class instance, and so whether or not to include it in the list.

If you are willing to slightly break separate compilation, by only considering instances that are in scope when the module that you are working on is *compiled* (i.e. that are in scope in that module's source file), you can use Template Haskell or GHC typechecker plugins to get something very much like this behavior. I know of a couple of implementations doing something similar at the value level, including [ifcxt](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ifcxt) and [constraints-emerge](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints-emerge). I believe that these libraries, especially ifcxt (which I am slightly more familiar with) are quite simple: you can use the TH function `reify` to get a `ClassI` `Info` for a particular typeclass, and use its `[InstanceDec]` field to get a list of all instances that are in scope during compilation. Then you can basically make one branch for each concrete type instance that adds the instance head to the list, and follow it up with one catch-all branch that will not. You may also need to do this recursively to deal with instances that have constraints themselves.

Notice that if you choose to use this approach, this will break the open-world assumption in potentially confusing ways: if a module imports the type-level filter module, and then defines a datatype/instance, the type-level filter will not be aware of the new instance, and will continue to treat the type as if it does not have an instance. You will need to make sure that all instances that you care about are in scope when you use TH to generate the filter type family.

If you want to improve this somewhat, you can use an approach even more like `IfCxt` where instead of creating the type family instances directly, you might be able to do something like this:

```
class IsShow (a :: Type) (b :: Bool) where
instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} (b ~ 'False) => IsShow a b where
```

And you have your TH generate instances like:

```
instance IsShow Int 'True where
```

This has the advantage that if another module defines important types/instances, you should be able to use (roughly) the same TH to extend the instances of `IsShow` with these new instances, and your type families that use `IsShow` should be fine. The ifcxt package linked above does basically the same thing, but instead of doing the necessary trickery to get the information at the type level, it just generates functions to get it at the value level.

This solution uses a class with functional dependencies instead of a type family because `OverlappingInstances` makes it possible to give the class-based solution a "default case". I'm not sure whether there's any reasonable way to give an *open* type family a default case, so you might not be able to get this "extensibility" while using type families everywhere (instead of fundep'd instances).

Richard Eisenberg [says](https://typesandkinds.wordpress.com/2012/12/22/ordered-overlapping-type-family-instances/)

> With separate compilation, the lack of ordering and the overlap check are necessary for type soundness.

So I think it may be impossible. There are also some interesting discussions around type families vs. fundeps here: https://typesandkinds.wordpress.com/2015/09/09/what-are-type-families/